# iPhone - initWithBarButtonSystemItem and language translation

Tags: iphone, translation, uibarbuttonitem

I use initWithBarButtonSystemItem to place some buttons in my navigationbar, but I am surprised with something : the text is not translated in the local language...

My keyboard "accept" text is in French, but UIBarButtonSystemItemSave keeps showing "Save" (in English) instead of something like "Enregistrer" or "Sauvegarder" (in French).

Is this normal ?
If yes, why use those kind of buttons instead of initWithTitle ones ?

Comment: Is your iOS simulator or device set to French? This is found under Settings > General > International.

Comment: @Brandon Schlenker : Yes, of course.

Comment: According to the docs these are definitely supposed to be localized. Are you on device or simulator?

Comment: @Brandon Schlenker : I'm on the simulator

Comment: Try installing on device. If your simulator is set to the desired language then it's a bug in the SDK because those should be localized. File a bug report. http://radar.apple.com

Comment: @Brandon Schlenker : Well... that's not for now... I'm not yet registered as a paid developer so I can't install yet on the device... Does this do the same on your simulator ?

Comment: Yes, the simulator as the same bug here.

Comment: @Brandon Schlenker : Could you post your comments as an answer to let me accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of the problem.

To make the translation work, you must define the languages to your project : Go to the project properties, and in the info tab, add the desired languages. Then, the System buttons will be localised on systems that use those languages. if you just let "English" as the sole language, for exemple, the System buttons won't be translated even if the app is launched on a Spanish, or French OS.